# How can I debug QXmlSchema's load method?

Tags: c++, qt, load, xsd

I'm trying to load the following XML Schema with `QXmlSchema`, however `QXmlSchema::load(const QUrl & source)` always returns `false`. Is there any way to have Qt provide some about what actually went wrong? The schema checks out fine in several validators as far as I can tell (the w3c one provided mysterious output that looked like it passed).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="message">
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:choice>

    <xsd:element name="login-reply">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="Accepted" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="Rejected" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="login-request" >
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" nillable="false"/>
          <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string" nillable="false"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="logout-request">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" nillable="false"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="logout-reply">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="Accepted" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="Rejected" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="tasklist-request" />

    <xsd:element name="tasklist-reply">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1">
          <xsd:element name="package" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="taskgroup" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                  <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" />
                      <xsd:element name="task" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                  </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="starttask-request">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="task-id" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="starttask-reply">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="Accepted" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="Rejected" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>

  </xsd:choice>

</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger ? You can recompile Qt if you're not sure about the compiler / debugger compatibility.

Comment: I can't recompile Qt with debug flags as it would break code. But there has to be some functionality to get an error message from Qt's parser?

Comment: Does QXmlSchema behave as expected for a trivially simple schema?  If so, keep adding things from your real schema to the trivial schema until you find out what's breaking things.  If not, check whether you're calling it correctly ...

Comment: So, you're saying you are using only the release version of Qt ? You should try to compile your application in *full* debug, ie Qt_debug + other_lib_debug + yourapp_debug.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. Read my first comment. I CANNOT compile debug versions of every thirdparty library this application uses. And this is besides the point. I am asking whether Qt has facilities to actually tell me why it rejects the schema.

Comment: From my experience of QXmlSchema, the short answer is no. Use a debugger with at least the provided debug version of Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bool QXmlSchema::load() itself returns only boolean result that is not really useful for debugging. But there this is more better way to get more appropriate error message.

You could use method [void QXmlSchema::setMessageHandler(QAbstractMessageHandler *handler)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlschema.html#setMessageHandler).

Here is example from my project.

First subclassing **QAbstractMessageHandler**

```
class MessageHandler : public QAbstractMessageHandler
{
public:
    MessageHandler() 
      : QAbstractMessageHandler(), 
        m_messageType(QtMsgType()), 
        m_description(),
        m_sourceLocation(QSourceLocation())
    {}

    QString statusMessage() const
    {
        return m_description;
    }

    qint64  line() const
    {
        return m_sourceLocation.line();
    }

    qint64  column() const
    {
        return m_sourceLocation.column();
    }
protected:
    virtual void handleMessage(QtMsgType type, 
                               const QString &description,
                               const QUrl &identifier, 
                               const QSourceLocation &sourceLocation) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        Q_UNUSED(type);
        Q_UNUSED(identifier);

        m_messageType = type;
        m_description = description;
        m_sourceLocation = sourceLocation;
    }
private:
    QtMsgType       m_messageType;
    QString         m_description;
    QSourceLocation m_sourceLocation;
};
```

Then before loading set message handler.

```
QFile file("myschema.xsd");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

MessageHandler messageHandler;
QXmlSchema sch;
sch.setMessageHandler(&messageHandler);
if (sch.load(&file, QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName()))==false)
{
    QString error = messageHandler.statusMessage();
    qint64 line = messageHandler.line();
    qint64 column = messageHandler.column();
    /*Do what need if error*/   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bool QXmlSchema::load() returns false on multiple conditions according to [this source documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qxmlschema.html#load)

So the answer to my question: No, there is no way to get an error message from Qts parser per Qt 4.7.3 and there is no way via Qts APIs to differentiate between an I/O error and a schema error, since load returns false on both.